# grep not working properly for bigger files > 200MB

Tags: grep

I am writing all matching lines from text files (one word per line) to an output file like so:

`grep "matchthis" input > output`

This works fine for files that are smaller than 200MB, however once the input file exceeds around 200MB grep writes around 14000 results into the output file (~59kb) and then stops. I know that the input file has at least 200.000 lines matching.

Do I need to provide any different parameters for bigger files or is grep not good enough for the job?

Comment: How does it stop? With an error message?

Comment: No, it just ends. As in "I'm done." If I check the output and take the last line and search for that in the input file, it's only about 1-2% through the input file and there's a lot of matching lines after that.

Comment: I naturally can't reproduce this, but in my experience, grep can manage huge files and I'm not aware of any limitations. Can you pinpoint an exact file size where it works, and you add a single line and it stops working?

Comment: grep will have no problem with a file that size. Are you sure you're not simply running out of space for writing the output file? How does the output of `awk '/matchthis/' input > output.awk` compare to the grep output? Please edit your question to include what `matchthis` really is so we can see if there's any issue with your regexp.